# How to reshape a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I'm new in python world. I need a help for a problem. I need to reshape a 3D array. 
This is an example:
I have:

```
[[[ 1 16 31]
  [ 2 17 32]
  [ 3 18 33]
  [ 4 19 34]
  [ 5 20 35]]

 [[ 6 21 36]
  [ 7 22 37]
  [ 8 23 38]
  [ 9 24 39]
  [10 25 40]]

 [[11 26 41]
  [12 27 42]
  [13 28 43]
  [14 29 44]
  [15 30 45]]]
```

I need to reshape it in:

```
[[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10]
 [11 12 13 14 15]]
[[16 17 18 19 20]
 [21 22 23 24 25]
 [26 27 28 29 30]]
[[31 32 33 34 35]
 [36 37 38 39 40]
 [41 42 43 44 45]]]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What ideas do you have?

Answer (score 2):

With the Einstein notation to switch axes

```
np.einsum("ijk->kij", arr)
```

Here is a nice introduction [Einstein Summation in Numpy](https://obilaniu6266h16.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/einstein-summation-in-numpy/)

Comment: Usually we use `transpose` to perform this sort of switich.

Comment: You are right, I couldn't remember the function. `arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)` works well.

Comment: Timings and the `__array_interface__` values suggest that the `einsum` approach is doing the same thing as `transpose`, but with just a bit more function overhead.  So if the syntax is easier to remember, use it.